# Prefabs were modified even it doesn't updated when commit

Tags: unity, git

Me and my co-workers uses Git for saving the developing game. But sometimes, some co-worker push the commit, it contains modified prefab that he never did.

Prefabs are binary files so I can't see what is changed until pull. The big problem is that those prefabs are already used other scenes so updating it's property might be cause unexpected behaviour.

Also if I do something work with one of that prefabs, that could be overwritten(or maybe not. git refuse the commit because of conflicts).

Anyway, my co-worker said he didn't touched any property of prefabs, even he didn't clicked it at all, but it still modified from his computer.

In this case, what makes those prefabs modified? How do I avoid those weird situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used to get this a lot with materials.

We tracked it down to one of our dynamic instantiation scripts, which took a shared base material, set the colour/texture/parameters to instance-specific values, *then* assigned an instance of the material to a renderer.

This meant the base material in our assets folder was constantly getting small changes made whenever we ran the game, and even though they happened in play mode, since it's an asset file, they're not undone when exiting back to edit mode. So they got saved to disc and Unity decided the asset had been modified and added it to the change list. But we didn't see any visible changes in-game, because the changes were only to parameters that we overwrite before use anyway, so it stayed mysterious for a long time.

Taking care to instantiate a copy of the asset first, *then* customize its instance-specific data stopped the phantom check-ins.

If it helps, you can [change your asset serialization mode to "Force Text"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EditorManager.html) to investigate what changes Unity thinks are being made, which might help track down their source.

Comment: For git isn't it pretty much a must to force text? Otherwise you're mostly working with binary files, which git isn't a fan of.

Comment: I can't say. I just know the question mentioned that the prefabs were currently binary.

Comment: Then OP should definitely force it to text.  @modernator check out [unity smart merge](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html) for prefabs and scene.